# verilog VPI Call Back

Tags: verilog

What is VPI call back `cbValueChange` supposed to do and how does it work?

Suppose I want to execute a function at the `posedge` of signal 
`X` (about 2000 cycles).  Should I use call back `cbValueChange` or call the code from the test bench?

```
always @posedge(X) 
begin 
    $pli 
end
```

Which would be more efficient?

Comment: What simulator are you using?

Comment: https://github.com/steveicarus/iverilog/blob/master/ivtest/vpi/nulls1.c

Comment: Generally if the single is one bit, then the `@(posedge X)` is better.  cbValueChange can be applied to a collection of bits, real, etc.  The always will not work in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Efficiency wise it probably doesn't matter much.  Without a better understanding of your situation it's tough to give solid advice but I recommend the $pli call as in your example.  Using cbValueChange means registering some C code to be executed by the simulator when the value of a variable changes.  This happens without a user defined $pli routine being called at the time the value changes.  Since this is completely invisible to anybody reading the Verilog code, you will frustrate anybody trying to understand what is going on if your C code makes any changes that affect the simulation.

Answer (score 0):

`cbValueChange` is the reason used to register/receive value change event for a registered signal via `vpi_register_cb()`. So when the signal value got flipped or changed, the simulator will invoke the callback function at the proper simulation phase. If you want to invoke your own PLI/VPI function only, you can see the detail example in http://www.asic-world.com/verilog/pli5.html